# Validity and Standing

Tags: patent-lifetime, priority, validity

In reference to the patent: [US6405939](https://www.google.com/patents/US6405939)

How long is this Patent standing and valid for?

Answer (score 0):

The definitive site to determine a US patent's status is the [US Public Pair](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair). In this case, the status is: Patent Expired Due to NonPayment of Maintenance Fees Under 37 CFR 1.362. The status date is 07-07-2014.